# How to display Image over a WebView?

Tags: android, webview, imageview

I am developing an app where I want an image over a WebView (Image on top of the WebView). I searched Google and tried many things. But it's not working.

In the design tab of the XML, I can see the image over the WebView. But when I load the app in my mobile the image does not appear but the web page loads.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/fabButton"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
app:srcCompat="@drawable/imag1"
android:elevation="2dp"
android:layout_marginEnd="41dp"

android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
 />


<WebView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:id="@+id/webView"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks for your help in advance.
I don't know if it affects the code or not but I'm trying to do this in a Fragment

Comment: add your Image View after your webview. ViewGroup mostly draws it child first come first serve basis, so in your code webviews hides the ImageView

Answer (score 1):

I hope it will help somebody. This is the code which I used:

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="3dp"
        tools:context=".CategoryActivity">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/inset_web_view"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/authTextView"
                android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Programs"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:textSize="20dp"/>

            <ScrollView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scrollbars="horizontal|vertical"
                android:scrollbarStyle="outsideInset"
                android:fillViewport="true">


                <WebView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:text="@string/programs"
                    android:textColor="#000"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="normal" />

            </ScrollView>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/viewButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:background="@drawable/roundedbutton"
                android:onClick="clickEvent"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="@string/apply_now"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>



    <WebView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/webView"
         />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/fabButton"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
        android:src="@drawable/circle"
        android:elevation="2dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="21dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"

        />
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: I tried your code but still does not appear. If i have no web site to load the image is visible but when the web site loads it does not appear